# Enabling global search for all profiles

Tags: custom-object, permissions, global-search

I am able to search `Inquiry_vod__c` object records in global search as admin but when logged in with any other user account, I am not able to search that object's record. Can somebody help?

1. Allow search checkbox is true for that object.
2. The profile from which I am logged in has read, create, edit and view all access for that `Inquiry_vod__c` object.

Comment: Did you check by selecting the object name in the left side of the page, under 'Search Results.

Comment: check the help article to trouble shoot the issue https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330207&type=1

Comment: What org wide default sharing do you have set for this custom object?